# eCharts: How to change line colors for positive and negative values?

Tags: echarts

I want to color the area "under" the graph (i.e. between zero and value) green when positive, and red when negative, on an eCharts line graph.

Like this
[image: Like this]

We have already done it with a bar graph (below), but now we need to do it with a line graph.

[image: bar graph]

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by setting the visualMap property. I have done some hit and trial and achieved the following.

```js
 var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));

 option = {
   xAxis: {
     type: 'category',
     boundaryGap: false,
     data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
   },
   yAxis: {
     type: 'value'
   },
   series: [{
     data: [820, 932, 901, -1200, -800, 1330, 1320],
     type: 'line',
     areaStyle: {}
   }],
   visualMap: {
     left: 'right',
     min: 0,
     max: 1,
     inRange: {
       color: ['red', 'green']
     },
     text: ['>0', '<0'],
     calculable: true
   },
 };

 // use configuration item and data specified to show chart
 myChart.setOption(option);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/4.6.0/echarts.min.js"></script>
<div id="main" style="width: 600px;height:400px;"></div>
```

Comment: Can I do this with a defined cutoff point instead of 0?